# Frenet frame plot for a point

Tags: plotting, curves

I would like to plot the curve $c(t) = \langle - \sin t, \cos t, t \rangle$ and its Frenet frame at $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$. The following is my code. However, it returns an error saying that Pi/2 is not a valid variable. Any help would be appreciated!

```
c[t_] := {-Sin[t], Cos[t], t};
cFSF[t_] := Simplify@Last@FrenetSerretSystem[c[t], t];

(*Plot the curve*)
curvePlot = 
  ParametricPlot3D[c[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
   ImageSize -> 400];

 (*Plot the Frenet-Serret frame at t=Pi/2*)
t0 = Pi/2;  
framePlot = 
  Graphics3D[{Arrow[{c[t0], c[t0] + cFSF[t0][[1]]}], 
    Arrow[{c[t0], c[t0] + cFSF[t0][[2]]}], 
    Arrow[{c[t0], c[t0] + cFSF[t0][[3]]}]}];

(*Show the plots together*)
Show[curvePlot, framePlot, ImageSize -> 400]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. There is an interactive example in the `Neat Examples` section of the `FrenetSerretSystem` doc page that shows the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"FrenetSerretSystem" needs symbolic input. Consider:

```
cFSF[1]
```

This evaluates to:

```
Simplify@Last@FrenetSerretSystem[{-Sin[1], Cos[1], 1}, 1]
```

"FrenetSerretSystem" then complains that "1" is not a valid variable. Therefore, to fix this, you need to evaluate the command before substituting numerical values. This is simply done by useing "Set" instead of "SetDelayed":

```
c[t_] := {-Sin[t], Cos[t], t};
cFSF[t_] = Simplify@Last@FrenetSerretSystem[{-Sin[t], Cos[t], t}, t];

(*Plot the curve*)
curvePlot = 
  ParametricPlot3D[c[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
   ImageSize -> 400];

(*Plot the Frenet-Serret frame at t=Pi/2*)
t0 = Pi/2;
framePlot = 
  Graphics3D[{Arrow[{c[t0], c[t0] + cFSF[t0][[1]]}], 
    Arrow[{c[t0], c[t0] + cFSF[t0][[2]]}], 
    Arrow[{c[t0], c[t0] + cFSF[t0][[3]]}]}];

(*Show the plots together*)
Show[curvePlot, framePlot, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: This makes much sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to force evaluation in the `SetDelayed` definition of cFSF:

```
cFSF[t_] := Evaluate@Simplify[Last@FrenetSerretSystem[c[t], t]]
```

Otherwise, you are passing a numeric `Pi/2` into the arguments of `FrenetSerretSystem` every time you call `cFSF`. It requires the variable `t`.

[FrenetSerretSystem](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrenetSerretSystem.html)

```
c[t_] := {-Sin[t], Cos[t], t};
cFSF[t_] := Evaluate@Simplify[Last@FrenetSerretSystem[c[t], t]]

(*Plot the curve*)
curvePlot = 
  ParametricPlot3D[c[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];

(*Plot the Frenet-Serret frame at t=Pi/2*)
t0 = Pi/2;
rTube = 0.02
framePlot = 
  Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[Tube[{c[t0], c[t0] + cFSF[t0][[1]]}, 
 rTube]],
 Green, Arrow[Tube[{c[t0], c[t0] + cFSF[t0][[2]]}, rTube]], Blue, 
 Arrow[Tube[{c[t0], c[t0] + cFSF[t0][[3]]}, rTube]]}];

(*Show the plots together*)
Show[curvePlot, framePlot]
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

```
curve = {-Sin[t], Cos[t], t};

frenet = Simplify @ Last[FrenetSerretSystem[curve, t]];

{tan, nor, bin} = Map[Arrow[{curve, curve + #}] &, frenet];

Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[curve, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}],
  Graphics3D[{Thick, Red, tan, Green, nor, Blue, bin} /. t :> Pi]]
```

[image]